# Docs for the internals of CPython Implementation

Tags: python, cpython

I am currently in the process of making an embedded system port of the CPython 3.0 Python interpreter and I'm particularly interested in any references or documentation that provides details about the design and structure of code for Release 3.0 or even about any of the 2.x releases.

One useful document I have found so far is this [informational PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0339/) on the implementation - which is a good overview - but is still pretty high level. Hoping to come across something that gives [much] more detail on more of the modules or perhaps even covers something about porting considerations.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298464/how-can-i-learn-more-about-python-s-internals

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's the documentation for the C API, which is essentially the API for the internals of Python.  It won't cover porting details, though.  The code itself is fairly well documented.  You might try reading in and around the area you'll need to modify.

Comment: Thanks (+1). I had looked at the official C API document and also the Extending/Embedding Python document. These are useful for my purposes, but the they are really looking at things from the outside. Ideally, I would like to find inside out type document - like the PEP but more comprehensive.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the documentation is stored in the minds of various core developers. :) A good resource for you would be the #python-dev IRC channel on freenode where many of them hang out.

There's also some scattered information on the [Python wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/).